# Need a GUI based deployment solution for .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, svn, git, deployment

Ok.. I have looked through this site and just can't seem to find the answer I am looking for.

We have a multi server setup for our web sites, typically (DEV/QA/PRODUCTION). Our sites are .net which require some sort of build before being deployed. We are using SVN for source control and are looking for a tool/website/something that will allow our project managers to push button deploy changes to the different environments. It seems there is no silver bullet for this, am I correct in this assumption?

I like the functionality of Springloops but can't find any information regarding its use with .net. Sparing details, it would be nice to see a diagram of sorts on the whole end to end process. What I mean by that is, if multiple different tools are the only answer (no silver bullet), then a diagram that shows where the tools sit in relation to the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [CruiseControl.Net](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/).  It'll let you automate your builds and if there are errors it can notify certain people and even flash a big red light in the office.

The other thing it can do is automatically deploy to a chosen region such as Dev/Test/Stage/Prod when there are no errors.

Though you may want to make Prod a manual press of a button. :)

Comment: We use it here and it works really really well.  Daily we have a build cycle that deploys to the testing domain on a good build.

Answer (score 0):

The new on click publishing features in Visual Studio 2010 are pretty easy to set up ans use: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/05/web-1-click-publish-with-vs-2010.html

Supports configuring IIS and deploying SQL packages too.

There is a msdeploy.exe file included in the that you could setup to run with .bat files or some configurable script runner.

Answer (score 0):

Try ClickOnce deployment. Once a update is deployed on the server the client applications are automatically get updated on every client on their next run.